# Kannel Make issue in Centos 7

Tags: centos7, kannel

I have tried to install kannel 1.4.5 in centos 7 but when run make command getting below error.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -D_REENTRANT=1 -I. -Igw -g -O2 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES= -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/openssl -o wmlscript/wslexer.o -c wmlscript/wslexer.c
wmlscript/wslexer.c:221:32: error: unknown type name ‘YYLTYPE’
 int ws_yy_lex(YYSTYPE *yylval, YYLTYPE *yylloc, WsCompiler* compiler)
                                ^
make: *** [wmlscript/wslexer.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of Bison used by CentOS isn't compatible with this code. According to [a bug report on this issue](https://redmine.kannel.org/issues/699),

> the problem occurs because bison 3 no longer supports YYLEX_PARAM and YYPARSE_PARAM. Both were have been deprecated since version 1.875, which was released on January 1, 2003

Not sure why it wasn't fixed in the latest release, but you can either downgrade to Bison 2.7 or apply [this patch](https://redmine.kannel.org/attachments/327/gateway-1.4.5.patch.gz) (linked from the bug report) to the code. The patch will:

> - remove YYLEX_PARAM and YYPARSE_PARAM #defines
> - add %lex-param and %parse-param directives
> - change all uses of void* pctx to WsCompiler* compiler
> - remove unnecessary casts from void* to WsCompiler*
> - modify the declaration of yyerror and move the declaration below %union so that it will have access to YYLTYPE.

Comment: Hi, I have applied this patch. before patch got two error. But now only getting this error.

Comment: Latest is (year 2017) https://github.com/markjeee/kannel ...... No errors.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say @KnudLarsen? But the repo is [here](https://redmine.kannel.org/projects/kannel/repository)

Comment: That's just a general think to do to get the latest version : Search app-name github. .... And then : `$ git clone https://github.com/markjeee/kannel.git`

Comment: And then you have an unoffical, out of date, and possibly altered codebase to work with.